# Fixed Port Addressing

Tags: assembly, x86

I am learning Fixed Port Addressing. The lecture says that its for 8 bits transfer. There were two examples given in it,

- IN AL, 6CH
- OUT 6AH, AX

Now the second one takes data from register AX which is a 16 bit register. Was it holding a 8 bit address or would it be transferred from a 16 bit address into a 8 bit address?

Comment: If you have a question about assembler, always tell us about the architecture and the OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`out 6ah, ax` will write both bytes of `ax` to the 16 bit I/O port at 0x6a. A 16 bit port consists of two consecutive 8 bit ports.

That is, it will write `al` to 0x6a and `ah` to 0x6b.

See [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual
Volume 1: Basic Architecture](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/253665.pdf) chapter 14.